# Best Organizational Structure for a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, oop, methods

I have a dataframe that I need passed through several methods in a class I am creating.  The only problem is, as I call each function, the changes that occurred on my previous function are not remembered in my next function.  Can someone please help with the organization of this code?  When I call my instance of the class, it says 'df is not defined.'

```
     def query(self):
        df = pd.read_sql('''
        SELECT date, city, flight  
        FROM TableName
        WHERE DATEPART(m, date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) 
        ORDER BY date
        ''', cnxn_str)
        return df

     def sort_df(self, df):
        df.head()


instance.query()
instance.sort_df()
```

````
<ipython-input-51-573e2eff6896> in <module>()
      1 Instance.query()
----> 2 Instance.sort_df(df)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `sort_df` function is expecting a passed argument:

```
def sort_df(self, df):
        df.head()
```

As you see, after defining the `self` parameter, you define a `df` element. Try passing a data frame element:

```
instance.query()
instance.sort_df(a_data_frame)
```

Greetings

Comment: I am trying to pass the dataframe element 'df' that was created in the previous function.  Does that element need to be set as a global variable or something?

Comment: It needs to be in the same scope, you could do the following:

a_data_frame = instance.query()
instance.sort_df(a_data_frame)